# Add Adobe Reader in prerequisite of my Setup project (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation

Am trying to add adobe reader in my setup project as pre-requisite, i don't know how to do this. I got this link but there is no Bootstrap generator in VS 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Kindly tell me is there any other way to add custom pre requisite in set up project of VS 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include additional installer with your setup installer in VS2010 with the help  [BMG_2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567). Just Build the Manifest using BMG_2008.

the Build results dialog box as you need to locate the generated files and manifest file, normally the location of this is here “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Your Installer” As this version of Bootstrapper Manifest Generator is version 2008 so it does generate in v6.0 folder. In order that this Prerequisites will appear in Visual Studio 2010 IDE you need to do some tricks.
Just  copy the whole folder to this path “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages“, the v7.0A folder is the location for all the Prerequisites Packages for Visual Studio 2010 Projects.

After copying you can now view this Prerequisites package on Prerequisite Dialog box of VS2010.

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12949670/)

Now, you can read [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx) again.